# BROKER_URL in Redis Cloud in Heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, redistogo, redislabs

Im working with Redis on Heroku, Im trying RedisToGo and Redis Cloud, I need to get the URL of the DB to put it in `BROKER_URL` in the settings of my django app. RedisToGo gives me clearly the URL in the dashboard, but Redis Cloud does not. Somebody knows how to get it?

Answer (score 2):

When you add the addon, the `REDISCLOUD_URL` gets set in the [config variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You should use the environment accessors in your app to use the URL, e.g. in Python `os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL')` and in Ruby `ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']`.

If you just want to know what the URL is, you can see it on the "Settings" tab on Heroku Dashboard--click "Reveal Config Vars." Or you can use the CLI:

`heroku config:get REDISCLOUD_URL -a YourAppName`